# NPM ERROR: npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

Tags: npm

while running my application I'm facing this error: npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

The log:

```
cat /home/harry/.npm/_logs/2021-09-09T11_15_34_872Z-debug.log
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
0 verbose cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'exec',
0 verbose cli   '--',
0 verbose cli   'babel-node',
0 verbose cli   '4-main.js'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.21.1
2 info using node@v16.9.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 3ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:/home/harry/HolbertonSchool/holbertonschool-web_back_end/0x0E-ES6_basic/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:/home/harry/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 2ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 14ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 14ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 3ms
24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 24ms
27 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-node 1083ms (cache miss)
28 timing command:exec Completed in 1122ms
29 verbose stack Error: could not determine executable to run
29 verbose stack     at getBinFromManifest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmexec/lib/get-bin-from-manifest.js:15:23)
29 verbose stack     at exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmexec/lib/index.js:113:15)
30 verbose pkgid babel-node@0.0.1-security
31 verbose cwd /home/harry/HolbertonSchool/holbertonschool-web_back_end/0x0E-ES6_basic
32 verbose Linux 5.4.0-52-generic
33 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "babel-node" "4-main.js"
34 verbose node v16.9.0
35 verbose npm  v7.21.1
36 error could not determine executable to run
37 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete `node_modules` and run `npm install` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue and looked at my package.json file to find that I had installed babel-node using npm babel-node rather than @babel/node

To fix it I removed "babel-node" and added "@babel/node": "7.x" then ran npm i again.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you could please mark my answer as useful it will help me out.